# C# Azure Function - CosmosDB Trigger and parsing document data

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on an Azure Function that runs on the CosmosDB trigger.
Microsoft has created this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function which works out nicely concerning the trigger.

I am now asking myself how to parse the returned document in a smooth way. The data I get back from the trigger function is from the class Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document (`IReadOnlyList<Document> documents`).

Any nice idea on how to parse those data into Json objects or comparable?

Thx!

Comment: you might already be able to do this out of the box by replacing `<Document>` with `<YourClass>`

Comment: unfortunately not... it only allows the `<Document>` class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Document` can be deserialized to any type you want, for example:

```cs
foreach (Document document in documents)
{
    MyClass myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(document.ToString());
}
```

You can also read any of its properties:

```cs
foreach (Document document in documents)
{
    string myPropertyValue = document.GetPropertyValue<string>("myProperty");
}
```

Comment: Great, that's how it should be done I guess. Interesting not many people have this problem, as I did not find a lot about that. Actually this is a super starting point I found really (too) late: https://www.tpeczek.com/2019/01/azure-functions-20-extensibility.html