# Retrieve specific data from Cosmos db using cosmos db trigger

Tags: c#, azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am able to connect with my cosmos database. I am able to retrieve the document and print the document using foreach loop i.e

> foreach (var document in documents) {    Console.Writeline(document) }

But I am not able to retrieve particular fields from the document. Can someone guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach (var document in documents) 
{ 
  Console.Writeline(document.GetPropertyValue<string>("myProperty")) 
}
```

Comment: document can be deserialized try this:                                                      [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874481/c-sharp-azure-function-cosmosdb-trigger-and-parsing-document-data)

Comment: I tried whats given in that post. It is giving something like functionname+classname